# How do I re-open an IntelliJ IDEA 12.0 CE project on Mac OS X Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I have just started using IntelliJ IDEA 12.0 Community Edition on Mac OS X 10.8.2 Mountain Lion, and recently created a Java project. During a recent file system clean-up, I moved my project folder to a different folder and deleted the link to the old location under the "Recent Projects" list on the welcome screen.

However, now I can't open my IntelliJ IDEA project at all. Browsing the file system, there does not appear to be a project file that I can select in the "Open Project" browser, nor can I double-click the project folder in Finder to open in IntelliJ IDEA. There is a hidden .idea folder inside the project, but it doesn't show in the "Open Project" browser, and Finder doesn't seem able to do anything about it.

If I double-click on my project folder from the IntelliJ IDEA "Open Project" browser, the "Open Project" browser disappears and nothing happens. No error message appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that I had two folders with the same name but different casing in the path to my project. For example:

```
/Volumes/USB HDD/Git
/Volumes/USB HDD/git/mygitproject/MyIntelliJIDEAProject
```

Because of the casing, the file system and user (me) know that the `git` and `Git` folders are distinct entities (admittedly, I should have used better names, but I was in the middle of a file system clean-up). IntelliJ IDEA 12.0 CE's project opening algorithms appear to be case insensitive, so when I double-clicked on `/Volumes/USB HDD/git/mygitproject/MyIntelliJIDEAProject`, IntelliJ IDEA failed to find a folder named `mygitproject` under `/Volumes/USB HDD/Git`, and the project failed to load.

I renamed `/Volumes/USB HDD/Git` to `/Volumes/USB HDD/Git.admin`, and I can now open my IntelliJ IDEA project by double-clicking the project folder from the "Open Project" browser window under `/Volumes/USB HDD/git/mygitproject/MyIntelliJIDEAProject`.

This is probably a minor bug in IntelliJ IDEA. I would have expected it to display an error message when it can't find the project folder.